# XSL to add wrapper element based on value change

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to create a 'wrapper' / parent element around my E1EDL20 elements when some values change. To be able to more or less group on that new element in SAP PO.
When the value in ABLAD changes or when I have a new VKORG I need to create the wrapper element.
I can create the element but I want the E1EDL20 to be part of that new group.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbL5Ydw/5

**Input xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287214</TKNUM>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018723</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018711</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018712</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018708</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018709</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**XSL:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
        
         <xsl:for-each select="//E1EDL20">
            <xsl:variable name="stopno" select="ABLAD"/>
            <xsl:variable name="salesorg" select="VKORG"/>

            <xsl:if test = "not ($stopno = preceding-sibling::E1EDL20/ABLAD) or not ($salesorg = preceding-sibling::E1EDL20/VKORG)">
              Grouping
              <GROUPBY><xsl:value-of select="$stopno" />_<xsl:value-of select="$salesorg" />
              </GROUPBY>           
            </xsl:if>  
            
                  <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                  </xsl:copy>

         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
      
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result:**

```
 <SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20>
              Grouping
              <GROUPBY>1_0100</GROUPBY>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
              Grouping
              <GROUPBY>1_0210</GROUPBY>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018723</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
              Grouping
              <GROUPBY>2_0200</GROUPBY>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018711</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018712</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
              Grouping
              <GROUPBY>3_0200</GROUPBY>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018708</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20>
            <VBELN>0081018709</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**Required result:**

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1EDT20>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018723</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018711</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018712</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018708</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
            <GROUPBY>
                <E1EDL20>
                    <VBELN>0081018709</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </GROUPBY>
        </E1EDT20>
    </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

As you can see the grouping on salesorg is not working correctly either because I would expect a new group for 0081018711 and 0081018712 (VKORG 0200 / VKORG 0100).

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: This is difficult to follow. I get the impression you're looking for `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-adjacent` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group. Certainly your method of testing for preceding siblings is grossly inefficient and shouldn't be used even in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Sorry Michael. Last time I tagged 1.0 incorrectly. I'll try to pay more attention next time. I've updated my post. Thanks for your comments / help!

Comment: In SAP PO I can handle 2.0. I accepted because of the additional 'if that is an xslt 2 processor'.  Updated the stylesheet and tag to 2.0. sorry..

Comment: Good. Do note that you need `group-adjacent` only if you expect the same combination of values to re-occur later in the XML and you do not want to merge the separate occurrences. Otherwise you could (and should)  use simply `group-by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a use case for `group-adjacent` e.g.

```
   <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="E1EDL20" group-adjacent="ABLAD || '|' || VKORG" >
            <GROUPBY>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </GROUPBY>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

(or, if that is an XSLT 2 processor, use `group-adjacent="concat(ABLAD, '|', VKORG)"`, as the `||` operator is XPath/XSLT 3).